# Xcode 11 problem with .h and .m class viewing

Tags: xcode, uikit

Yesterday I started having an issue with the Assistant Editor in Xcode 11.  Now, when I have Main.storyboard selected and select Option + ViewController.swift, I new get to choose between two different .h classes (ViewController.h and NavigationController.h). I can no longer get the Navigation Area, the Interface Builder, and the .m View Controller class adjacent to one another. I am able get the Navigation Area, the Interface Builder and either ofthe .h files adjacent to one another.

I cleaned the build folder, shut down and restarted Xcode, restarted my MacBook, moved Xcode to the Trash and installed from a new download.  I created a new project and I do not have the same issue with the new project that I have with the legacy project. I cannot think of anything that I may have done that is project specific to achieve this result.

I hope that I've include enough information for someone to give me a tip. If not, please ask me to include any additional information please. I included a screenshot from the other day when it was working "correctly".

Many thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed a work around. I exported the Main.Storyboard and imported that object into a new project.  The problem that I had not being able to view .m class files did not follow the storyboard file.